# Powershell Combine SQL Scripts and Run Against MySQL

Tags: mysql, powershell

My question is a two-part question. In command line I can do the following to combine a couple SQL scripts:

```
copy /b *.sql foo.sql
```

And then run it against a MySQL database using:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [password] [database] < "C:\Location\Of\File\foo.sql"
```

How would I go about doing this in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work

```
Get-Content 'c:\pathToSql\*.sql' | mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD
```